# Arduino use as USB Mass Storage

Tags: arduino, arduino-due

Is there any way to use arduino as USB mass storage device.I want to copy a file from the computer to arduino as pen drive?

Comment: Do you want to use just an Arduino without any SD cards, shields etc.? Are you aware of its memory limitations?

Comment: i want to copy a file to sd card or whatever memory device from the computer.but computer want to identify the device as a Mass storage device, like a pen drive.can I implement it.

Comment: I believe the following links are useful
[this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=308436.0) and
[this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=37393.0)

This one not really arduino, but related
[check this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-mass-storage-for-your-microcontroller-proje/)